# Gradle sync failed: Could not determine artifacts for com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0

Tags: android, synchronization, build.gradle

I am unable to `sync` my `build.gradle` the below error is showing

> Gradle sync failed: Could not determine artifacts for
>   com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0: No cached version
>   available for offline mode

Comment: post your bulid.gradle code .

Comment: At first `Clean-rebuild` your project & you can use `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'` . Please show your `build.gradle`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To solve this use this way.

1. Uncheck  `Offline work` in Android Studio

   go this way

   `File`->`Settings`->`Build, Execution, Deployment`->`Build tools->Gradle`.
2. `Resync` the project, by restarting the Android Studio.
3. Once synced, you can check the option again to work offline.

Answer (score 0):

Setting->Build,Execution,Deployment->Build tools->gradle, disable offline work, click ok then.

Comment: i did it but still showing an error Failed to resolve:com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0